# R ggbiplot installation errer

Tags: r, installation, ggbiplot

I know this is a recurrent issue. However, going through all the hits when I google still has not helped me solve the issue. I hope someone can help: Her is what I do:
1: I run

```
install.packages('devtools')
library(devtools)
```

This appears to run all right. At least I do not get any error messages.

2: then I do:

```
install_github('vqv/ggbiplot', force=TRUE)
```

Then the errors messages comes:

> install_github('vqv/ggbiplot', force=TRUE)
>   Downloading GitHub repo vqv/ggbiplot@master
>   √  checking for file 'C:\Users\jada\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpgvAEpK\remotes28461c455b1\vqv-ggbiplot-7325e88/DESCRIPTION' ...
>   -  preparing 'ggbiplot':
>   √  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... 
>   -  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
>   -  checking for empty or unneeded directories
>   -  looking to see if a 'data/datalist' file should be added
>   -  building 'ggbiplot_0.55.tar.gz'

Installing package into ‘C:/Users/jada/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package 'ggbiplot' ...
** using staged installation
** R
** data
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error: (converted from warning) package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 3.6.1
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'ggbiplot'
* removing 'C:/Users/jada/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/ggbiplot'
Error: Failed to install 'ggbiplot' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘C:/Users/jada/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpgvAEpK/file28421d56f74/ggbiplot_0.55.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

> 

If anyone could sort me out here, I would be very happy.
Thank you.

jd

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to go in the path of the library in your computer (should be c:/Users/jada/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/) and delete the ggbiplot folder. After this, redo the installation process.
In this way you remove every possible problem conflict.

If this doesn't work out try also to delete ggbiplot_0.55.tar.gz in the Temp folder as suggested in the error.

Comment: Thanks for your getting back. However, none of these files/folders were present on my computer.

Comment: Ok I try reading again the error status. Maybe the error is the the ggplot2 library as here  `Error: (converted from warning) package 'ggplot2' `. So try delete ggplot2 (instead of ggbiplot) library folder directly in the path C:/Users/jada/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/ggplot2, then try reinstall the two packages

Comment: No, that did not make any difference. Looks like the return is pretty much the same:

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old question, but I have found a solution in [here](https://github.com/vqv/ggbiplot/issues/59), and just in case the link does not work, here is the possible solution:

```
install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_github("vqv/ggbiplot")
```